how to display current date in text input's placeholder in react native
             `<View style={styles.dateInput}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>To Date</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showDatePicker(false)}>
                <TextInput
                  placeholder="Select Date"
                  value={toDate}
                  editable={false}
                  style={styles.dateinput}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <DateTimePickerModal
              isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
              mode="date"
              onConfirm={handleDateConfirm}
              onCancel={hideDatePicker}
            />`

i want to display current date in place of "Select Date" in placeholder. i have a datepicker input for selcting the date.

You need a state for save toDate value.
And with dayjs. you can show it ez:
           <View style={styles.dateInput}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>To Date</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showDatePicker(false)}>
                <TextInput
                  placeholder="Select Date"
                  value={dayjs(toDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
                  editable={false}
                  style={styles.dateinput}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <DateTimePickerModal
              isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
              mode="date"
              onConfirm={handleDateConfirm}
              onCancel={hideDatePicker}
            />
    

